# Why can't I import anything in Android Studio(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am fairly new to android studio and am trying to link a button to another project. I have the code right and I am trying to import 'Intent' but it will not let me. It gives me an error with the bundle when I try to remove the '...' and won't let me type anything around it. Any help would be appreciated.[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv8YF.png)

Comment: Clearly, your code is unable to detect the Intent class. Are you missing the import statement for the Intent? Can you expand your imports and paste here?

Comment: My problem is that it won't let me import Intent. It will not let me edit the import statement in the code nor will it let add another import statement.

Answer (score 0):

When your cursor is on the line, try clicking Alt+Enter, and it should bring you to a list for options where importing intent should be one of them.
If this doesn't work, then you can also import intent manually.